# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED code included

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

Okay, so I have been searching and searching and have not found any help. When I launch the AVD, it says:

```
No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

Once the emulator opens, this comes up.

```
Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
```

I'm pretty sure that my AndroidManifest is correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mshaw.avanos"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    <activity
        android:name=".AvanosActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `application` and `activity` tags have no closing `>`.

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mshaw.avanos"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
    android:name=".AvanosActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```