# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, android-manifest, logcat

i am getting strange issue while installing app.

I have create `Google Map V2 example` and its working fine. 
After all success i have integrate `JAVA` -`XML` - `Manifest` file in my older project.

When i compileing my project there is no error but when i trying to launch its shows me

`Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED` Error.

I am following [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=fr#specifying_permissions) for Google Map V2 exmaple.

The Logcate is strang. i am unable to find issue.

i have tried so many thing related  `Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED` error and also follow that rule but something goes wrong.

**Rnd Wrok :**

[How to fix INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in my android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396351/how-to-fix-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed-in-my-android-application)

[Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED code included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174275/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed-code-included)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/RoghZWPRK_s

If i remove new example files and run older project then its running okay.

Please guys help me.

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.pkg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="my.pkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="my.pkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:theme="@style/mytheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="my.pkg.Google_Map" >
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAULMOV1ylxC7wvEIP1hP7EeuKr1dKLaVQ" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Update :**

**Logcate**

```
04-15 17:33:37.685: E/power(1482): *** set_screen_state 1
04-15 17:33:37.692: E/SensorManager(1482): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= BMA222 delay= 60000 Listener= android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@406996b8
04-15 17:33:37.692: E/SensorManager(1482): reg :: handle = 0
04-15 17:33:37.786: E/ClockWidget(17093): getOrientation portrait
04-15 17:33:37.786: E/ClockWidget(17093): drawDayText
04-15 17:33:37.786: E/ClockWidget(17093): width= 50
04-15 17:33:37.786: E/ClockWidget(17093): widthText= 58.0
04-15 17:33:37.786: E/ClockWidget(17093): RIGHT
04-15 17:33:37.810: E/Launcher(1587): setWindowOpaque()
04-15 17:33:38.692: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): ecio: 38
04-15 17:33:38.692: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): iconLevel: 4
04-15 17:33:40.653: E/power(1482): *** set_screen_state 0
04-15 17:33:40.653: E/SensorManager(1482): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@406996b8
04-15 17:33:40.653: W/PowerManagerService(1482): CurLockF mPS:0 mUS=0
04-15 17:33:40.653: W/PowerManagerService(1482): type=FULL_WAKE_LOCK                 'keyguard' AW  (mS=7)  activeT=272
04-15 17:33:40.653: W/PowerManagerService(1482): mPokeLocks.size=0:
04-15 17:33:40.755: E/AndroidRuntime(27309): feature code ==> cannot open file
04-15 17:33:41.021: E/power(1482): *** set_screen_state 1
04-15 17:33:41.052: E/SensorManager(1482): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= BMA222 delay= 60000 Listener= android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@406996b8
04-15 17:33:41.052: E/SensorManager(1482): reg :: handle = 0
04-15 17:33:41.146: E/Launcher(1587): setWindowOpaque()
04-15 17:33:41.169: E/ClockWidget(17093): getOrientation portrait
04-15 17:33:41.169: E/ClockWidget(17093): drawDayText
04-15 17:33:41.169: E/ClockWidget(17093): width= 50
04-15 17:33:41.169: E/ClockWidget(17093): widthText= 58.0
04-15 17:33:41.169: E/ClockWidget(17093): RIGHT
04-15 17:33:42.997: W/ActivityManager(1482): No content provider found for: 
04-15 17:33:43.817: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): ecio: 38
04-15 17:33:43.817: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): iconLevel: 4
04-15 17:33:46.286: E/power(1482): *** set_screen_state 0
04-15 17:33:46.286: W/PowerManagerService(1482): CurLockF mPS:0 mUS=0
04-15 17:33:46.286: W/PowerManagerService(1482): mPokeLocks.size=0:
04-15 17:33:46.294: E/SensorManager(1482): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@406996b8
04-15 17:33:46.364: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): ecio: 37
04-15 17:33:46.364: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): iconLevel: 4
04-15 17:33:47.075: W/ActivityManager(1482): No content provider found for: 
04-15 17:33:51.497: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): ecio: 36
04-15 17:33:51.497: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): iconLevel: 4
04-15 17:33:54.060: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): ecio: 35
04-15 17:33:54.060: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): iconLevel: 4
04-15 17:33:56.630: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): ecio: 33
04-15 17:33:56.630: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): iconLevel: 4
04-15 17:34:00.005: E/ClockWidget(17093): getOrientation portrait
04-15 17:34:00.005: E/ClockWidget(17093): drawDayText
04-15 17:34:00.005: E/ClockWidget(17093): width= 50
04-15 17:34:00.005: E/ClockWidget(17093): widthText= 58.0
04-15 17:34:00.005: E/ClockWidget(17093): RIGHT
04-15 17:34:01.732: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): ecio: 32
04-15 17:34:01.732: E/StatusBarPolicy(1544): iconLevel: 4
```

Comment: `LogCat` link appears to be broken.

Comment: @Asok thanks for repaly.i have update that,please check it again

Comment: Also bad practise to link to your files, include them here in the post instead. (logcat and manifest)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It was very difficult to find the solution because `Logcat` said something else. Finally I found the solution for my above query.

The issue was in my package name: I had set the first character of the package name to a **capital letter** like `Chintan.Khetiya.Package`.

Generally, that was working for me in my older project, but when I tried to implement Google Maps code in my existing project, then the **Manifest File** is not allowed to use a **capital letter** in the package name.

So, finally I replaced it with lowercase characters like `chinta.khetiya.package`, and updated my new Google Maps Key with the new package name.

Now it's working.

So be careful when you set your package name. [See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075162/what-should-be-the-package-name-of-android-app/8075247#8075247).

Comment: I think also your activity name should start with a dot `.`. +1 for your solution tho.

Comment: This is so wierd. Even though my namespaces contain capital letters "NamespacePart1.NameSpacePart2.ActivityClassName" i had to lowercase it but leave the class name as is: "namespacepart1.namespacepart2.ActivityClassName". But it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this - this is the sort of issue you could pull your hair out over for days, so thank goodness for Stackoverflow and internet search..

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to your comment usage in your manifest file.
You cannot use comments like this in your Manifest:

```
// new update
```

You'll have to use the XML way, like so:

```
<!-- new update -->
```

//// EDIT:

Actually, you're using a custom permission before declaring the permission. Try turning this part around:

```
<uses-permission android:name="my.pkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="my.pkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

to

```
<permission
        android:name="my.pkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="my.pkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: i haven't add comment in my manifest file , its just for highlight.thanks for replay

Comment: Ah, my bad. Took a closer look and found probably found the actual reason.

You declare using a custom permission, before actually declaring this permission. Try turning this part around:

<uses-permission android:name="my.pkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="my.pkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Comment: Alright, last thing I can think of is the `meta-data` tag. You can only use those within `activity`, `<activity-alias>`, `<service>` and `<receiver>`, yet you use it within your `<application>` tag. This might cause problems. (Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html)

Comment: yes it may be true but in this case see here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=fr#specifying_permissions they are saying add before </application>

Comment: Hmm alright. Way to go Google, not following your own guidelines. Sorry man, out of ideas then. Good luck!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28253/discussion-between-chintan-khetiya-and-sander-vant-veer)

Comment: @sSander van't Veer you good luck is worked for me. thanks +1 for help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your package name should start with lower case letter.
Suppose you have:

```
Com.Example.packagename
```

Changed it to something like

```
com.example.packagename
```

That will solve your problem.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks for the answer... it's so lame that we have to put all capital letter into smaller case.

Answer (score 0):

You should add android:name=".Splash" instead of android:name="Splash"

Modified code below:::HAPPY CODING :)

```
<activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: The OP already found the problem and created an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you set export to false or somehow delete the line set export line in the manifest file then it could give the error mentioned as above

```
<activity
        android:name="com.aditya.flappybird.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:exported="true">
```

if the `android:exported="true"` is not present on the above code then just add this line in your manifest file and you are good to go