# Failed to load memtrack module -2

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I am writing code for an android app on eclipse. However I came across the error:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED.
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

None of the posted answers (changing things to lowercase/making sure everything is closed etc...) fixed this problem.

**StackTrace Error:**

```
Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory) 
Failed to  load memtrack module: -2.
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Thanks
Z

Comment: check this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015033/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed/16030352#16030352

Comment: I checked that post already but nothing there seemed to help much.

Comment: Refer these Stackoverflow question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat‌​-error`.The nice answer with explanation would be given by Fllo.Hope it may be helpful to you.

Comment: Answered it here for `Xamarin` developers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707459/1876355

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is kind of old but I ran across the same issue today with the same error
from Logcat :
`failed to load memtrack module: -2` or 
`couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)` 
upon inspection the issue seems to come from the 
`AndroidManifest.xml` 
from declaring the following attribute inside the manifest tag

`<manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal">`

the attribute's value is misleading since I would assume that if it didn't find an external location(SD Card) the package would just be installed in internal memory, but apparently that is not the case. So either verify that there is an external storage or remove the attribute.

Comment: Refer these Stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat‌​‌​-error.The nice answer with explanation would be given by Fllo.Hope it may be helpful to you.